# Отступ для блоков в контенте: снизу, сверху или везде?

Tags: html, вёрстка

Где оптимальнее делать отступ (`padding` или `margin`) у стандартных блоков (`H1—H6, ul, p, blockquote` и т.д.) внутри контента страницы?
Жду аргументированного ответа.

Comment: Ну что значит оптимальнее? Поговорите с Вашим дизайнером, и верстайте.

Comment: Думаю нужно конкретнее объяснить что к чему.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Прежде чем задавать подобные вопросы, взгляните на Ваш макет и если необходимо, прочитайте ТЗ, Вам сразу все станет ясно - появиться четкое осознание того, где и какие именно отступы необходимы.

Если макета и ТЗ нет, и Вы просто верстаете какое-либо свое творение, то тут полагайтесь на Ваши дизайнерские способности.

Ваш вопрос, сродни извечному вопросу женщин - "Что мне надеть?"

В общем, решайте сами. Внизу представлены примеры использования свойств padding и margin, а уж для каких сторон Вы их зададите - дело Ваше.

---

[[@jfk](/users/4728/jfk)](/users/4728/jfk), *если Вы хотите получать аргументированные ответы, научитесь правильно задавать вопросы. На данный момент, Ваш вопрос, видимо, понятен только Вам.* Тем не менее, попытаюсь Вам помочь ...

---

**Немного терминологии:**

**padding** - *устанавливает значение полей вокруг содержимого элемента. Полем называется расстояние от внутреннего края рамки элемента до воображаемого прямоугольника, ограничивающего его содержимое*

**margin** - *устанавливает величину отступа от каждого края элемента. Отступом является пространство от границы текущего элемента до внутренней границы его родительского элемента*

**Исходя из вышеописанного делаем нехитрый вывод:** отступы *padding* и *margin*, необходимо использовать по их прямому назначению.

Пример 1 - [отступ контента от внутренней границы блока](http://jsfiddle.net/Alex83/AsjuK/).

Пример 2 - [отступы элементов друг от друга.](http://jsfiddle.net/Alex83/dJsNH/1/)

---

С помощью этих разных свойств, зачастую, можно добиться одного визуального результата.
В общем, применяйте отступы и поля, в зависимости от ситуации и конкретно поставленной задачи.

Удачи

**UPD:** Верстается по макету и «серебряной пули» не существует. Все делается в зависимости от конкретной задачи и ситуации.

Comment: Спасибо за столь развернутый ответ. 
У меня за плечами не один десяток веб-проектов под ключ (спецификации и назначение padding и margin мне знакомы не по наслышке =) ). Просто в каждом новом проекте при подборе расположений отступов руководствовался именно макетом, а не какой-то единой методологией. Работая над новым сайтом задумался, что это, возможно, не рационально, и у цеха верстальщиков есть готовое, продуманное, обоснованное решение (например здесь в ответах отступы у текстовых блоков снизу) Но судя по комментариям «серебряной пули» не существует и каждый верстает «от макета».

Comment: @jfk, при таком контексте, данный вопрос вполне разумен, поэтому, вопросу +.

Серебряной пули конечно не существует, но давайте поразмышляем ...

Допустим, если идет заголовок и за ним некий абзац текста и  таких (назовем их блоками "заголовок-абзац") больше одного на странице, то вероятно логичнее будет задать верхний и нижний padding для заголовка.

Если же структура иная, а именно - заголовок и под ним несколько абзацев с отступами, то в данном случае, разумнее будет задать верхний отступ (padding или margin) для абзацев.

То есть, снова приходим к тому, что все верстается по ситуации.

Comment: @Astor, во втором примере не соглашусь: в реальной жизни контент может размещаться людьми несведущими и текст может запросто остаться без заголовка, в таком случае на странице появится незапланированный просвет, поэтому отступы снизу в данном случае кажутся мне уместнее.

Comment: @jfk, это не догма ... и опять же, все в зависимости от конкретной ситуации ...